# Firestore: Increment some numeric field by a variable number using an AJAX post. NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have 11 different numeric fields for every user in my application. I want to build an api to increment one of those fields by a certain amount.

The request would be of this form:

```
{
   "uid":"Qewqhfui7232289",
   "field":"someName",
   "value":13.4
}
```

The api would then retrieve the document with id "uid" and increment the field someName by 13.4

Most of the examples I see are incrementing a specific field by a constant.

Something like this (but that actually works):

```
var router = express.Router();
router.post('/increment', function (req, res, next) {
    var ref = db.collection('UserInfo').doc(req.body.uid);
    var field=req.body.field;
    var value=req.body.value;

    var transaction = db.runTransaction(function(t) {
            return t.get(ref)
        .then(function(doc) {
            var updated= doc.data().field + value;
            t.update(ref, {field: updated);
            });
    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log('Transaction success!');
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
    });
res.send("response");
});
```

Do I need to create an api for every single field?

And does firestore support variable incrementation (ie not a hard-coded number)?

EDIT: Some clarifications::

1)I am just planning on editing single documents, not several.

2)I want to create an api that is able to increment any field according to request body input (instead of creating an api for each field). But that's not essential as I can just create several api's.

3)My TOP PRIORITY is to know how to increment using a variable that is set using req.body.value rather than a fixed number that's hard-coded into the api.

EDIT2: I settled for creating an API for each field.

Answer (score 0):

A single call to `Document.update()` can update multiple fields in a document. But it can only update a single document.

> Do I need to create an api for every single field?

If the fields are in a single document, you can update them all with one call like:

```
var data= doc.data();
t.update(ref, {field: data.field + value, field2: data.field2 + value, field3: data.field3 + value);
```

> And does firestore support variable incrementation (ie not a hard-coded number)?

There is currently no API to tell the database server to "increment this field", but that is being considered and work has even been done on it. As usually though there are no guarantees when (or even if) this feature will make it into a release.

Comment: What I meant is, I want to send a string and a number in the request body. Then the api will increment the field with the same name as the string sent through the request by the number sent in the request. For example: A request such as {"id":1234,"field":age,"number":2} will increment age field in document with id 1234 by 2. Instead of having one api for incrementing age, one for incrementing height, etc

Comment: My project is a cloud manager (transfer files from one cloud to another) and I want to keep track of the total size of files transferred by each user. So I wanna keep incrementing certain fields like "oneDriveUpload" by a float.

Comment: "A request such as {"id":1234,"field":age,"number":2}" Isn't that what my example does?